# Read Azure Datalake Gen2 images from Azure Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks, rasterio, azure-data-lake-gen2

Am working on `.tif` files stored in Azure Data Lake Gen2.  Want to open this files using `rasterio` from Azure Databricks.

Example:

when reading the image file from Data Lake as `spark.read.format("image").load(filepath)` works fine.

[image]

But trying to open same as

```
with rasterio.open(filepath) as src:
    print(src.profile)
```

getting error:

```
RasterioIOError: wasbs://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxx_2016/xxxx_2016.tif: No such file or directory
```

Any clues what am doing wrong?

Update:

As suggest by Axel R, mounted files on Databricks file system but still getting same issue and cannot open the file from rasterio, but can read as df.

[image]

Also tried by created shared access signature to the file in Datalake and tried to access the file through URI.  Now getting error below error:

```
CURL error: error setting certificate verify locations:   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none
```

To test further tried to open a sameple file from web which is @

`filepath = 'http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/c1/L8/042/034/LC08_L1TP_042034_20170616_20170629_01_T1/LC08_L1TP_042034_20170616_20170629_01_T1_B4.TIF'` works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because rasterio is using the Local APIs and can only read from a path that starts with /dbfs/.

Is it possible for you to mount the blob storage ? That would allow you to access it with rasterio with a path starting with /dbfs/mnt/

Comment: I agree with this answer. This also suggests a blocking operation that will run on the driver only leaving the workers idle. Generally something you want to avoid.

Comment: After mount into databricks, was reading files as 'dbfs:/mnt/Firescar/cvmsre_201910_afka2.tif' when changed to '/dbfs/mnt/Firescar/cvmsre_201910_afka2.tif'  all works